LTSpice full bridge rectifier is acting like a half bridge rectifier
This is the circuit I have setup, with the output of bridge plotted under it.
Why is it that the full bridge rectifier is acting like a half bridge rectifier.
As in, why are there periods of 0V between the waves?


Because you grounded D4 on both sides. It's like not having it since the potential on both sides is the same and no current flows through it ever.
This is the correct way to do it:

Image taken from: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bridge-rectifier/
I suggest you read the article too.
But to fix your schematic, gnd used on the source should be different (different potential) to gnd used on the load.

Thanks, removing the ground from the source fixed it.

I will try and google how I can use a different gnd for the source

It's like not* having it

Usually the source is a secondary stage of a transformer, so it is not grounded.. it's just Vsec-, while the positive side is vsec+. "Sec for secondary".

Note that most simulators won't work without a ground reference in the circuit.

But there will be, just not on the source, on the load. If it's needed on the source use a different ground

@ursusd8  Umm.... Did you check your bridge rectifier connections?

@ursusd8  What I mean is that you did not take a good look at the picture you posted in your answer.

@EdinFifić thank you, I thought I was crazy when I looked at that and said: "This doesn't look right". ursusd8 if you go to your source, you will see that there is another picture right below the one you pasted, and half the diodes are in a different orientation. You might want to figure out which one is the "real" bridge.

@ursusd8 Could you please fix the diagram? Take a look at the polarity of the diodes and compare with the other ones. Even in the source you linked the correct one is shown.

This isn't really an answer, but a clarification of a comment. @Edin Fifić said:

@ursusd8 Umm.... Did you check your bridge rectifier connections?

I'm pretty sure this is referring to the fact that the full wave bridge should normally look like this:

Note the change in orientation of the diodes. As it's drawn in the figure from geeks for geeks, you have something that creates essentially a dead short during one half of each cycle, and never has any (useful) potential difference between the two output lines (the only voltage you'll see will be from mismatch between the diodes).

It is not like D4 is not there. It is shorted:

This is the positive semi-cycle:

This is the negative one (poor D2):

